# Passing data from Vue.js request to Laravel 5.3 form

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have two tables: Countries and Cities. Idea is to show the second dropdown when User has selected country and fill it with cities that correspond to selected country.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to pass retrieved values to form.

Values retrieved are below the country with id 21 is Norway :)

Selected { "country": "21", "CountrySelected": true, "cities": { "6": "Oslo", "11": "Lillehammer" } }

```js
// My app.js

const app = new Vue({


el: '#events',

  data: {
    country:'',
    CountrySelected: false, 
    cities:[],  
  },

  methods: {

    WhenCountryHasBeenSelected: function(event) {
     this.getCities();
     this.CountrySelected= true;
    },

    getCities: function(){
     this.$http.get('api/cities/'+this.country).then(function (response) {
      this.cities = response.data;
      });
   }
  },

})
```

```html
//My api.php routes

Route::get('/cities/{country_id}', function (Request $request, $country_id) {
  
$cities=App\City::where('country_id', $country_id)->get()->pluck('name','id');

return $cities;
});


//My blade file

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div id="events">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Select cities by country</div>

                <div class="panel-body">


                    {!! Form::open() !!}


                    {!! Form::select('country', $countries, null,  ['v-model'=>'country', '@change'=>'WhenCountryHasBeenSelected' ,'class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                 
                    <div v-show="CountrySelected">
                    {!! Form::select('city',$cities, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                   
                    Selected @{{ $data | json }}
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up to use Laravel collection map feature. Mu route looks now like this

```
Route::get('/cities/{country_id}', function (Request $request, $country_id) {
        $collection=App\City::where('country_id', $country_id)->get();
        $cities=$collection->map(function($city){
            return ['id' => $city->id, 'name' => $city->name];
            })->toArray();
```

Long live Laracast forums and bashy :)